# Login using Facebook

Tags: jquery, node.js

In my site I included the login using facebook.It's working correctly,if the user enters the email_id. But the problem is in facebook there is an option for new user to register with mobile number, I didn't included mobile number in my site i.e., I am validating only with email_id's. If the user go to my site login with facebook ,if he login with mobile number throwing an error how to handle this ? can anyone help me?

Comment: I dont think there should be any problem with that, once the user logs in using facebook login screen, facebook should return you some user info of the logged in user, and email *must* be present there.

Comment: Yes, what you said is correct, but in facebook we have an option login with mobile number also. I am not handling in my site if the user enters the mobile number. If he enters  with email-id it will be redirected to my site.